# How do I copy contents from one column to another while using .apply() in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, currency-formatting

I have a DataFrame with 2 columns `total_open_amount` and `invoice_currency`.

`invoice_currency` has

```
USD    45011
CAD     3828
Name: invoice_currency, dtype: int64
```

And I want to convert all the CAD to USD from the total_open_amount column wrt to invoice_currency with an exchange rate of 1 CAD = 0.7USD and store them in a separate column.

My code:

```
df_data['converted_usd'] = df_data['total_open_amount'].where(df_data['invoice_currency']=='CAD')
df_data['converted_usd']= df_data['converted_usd'].apply(lambda x: x*0.7)
df_data['converted_usd']
```

output:

```
0            NaN
1            NaN
2            NaN
3        2309.79
4            NaN
          ...   
49995        NaN
49996        NaN
49997        NaN
49998        NaN
49999        NaN
Name: converted_usd, Length: 48839, dtype: float64
```

I was able to fill the new column with CAD values converted but how do I fill the rest of the USD values now?

Comment: Will you please provide a sample of your whole dataframe? Try `print(df.head(5).to_dict())`

Comment: @richardec its too long to fit in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) or [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html), [`series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) set to NaN the rows where `'invoice_currency'` is USD, but with the **other** parameter we tell it that these values ​​have to be filled with `df_data['total_open_amount']` series multiplied by 0.7.

using [`serie.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) the rows that do not meet the condition are set to NaN, so first we multiply the series by 0.7 and leave only the rows where the condition is met, that is, the rows with USD currency and we use **other** parameter to leave the rest of rows with initial value

Note that [series.mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [series.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) are the opposite of each other.

```
df_data['converted_usd'] = df_data['total_open_amount']\
    .mask(df_data['invoice_currency'] == 'CAD', 
          other=df_data['total_open_amount'].mul(0.7))
```

Or:

```
df_data['converted_usd'] = df_data['total_open_amount'].mul(0.7)\
    .where(df_data['invoice_currency'] == 'CAD', 
          df_data['total_open_amount'])
```

**numpy version**

```
df_data['converted_usd'] = \
np.where(df_data['invoice_currency'] == 'CAD',               
         df_data['total_open_amount'].mul(0.7), 
         df_data['total_open_amount'])
```

Comment: wow that worked like a charm but do you mind explaining me how it works?

Comment: so if I use .mask(), i will be filling up the column with USD values and modified CAD values (into USD) as well?

Comment: series.mask set to NaN the rows where 'invoice_currency' is USD, but with the other parameter we tell it that these values ​​have to be filled with this series multiplied by 0.7

Comment: so if use where then the rows where 'invoice_currency' is USD are not set to NaN?

Comment: using where the rows that do not meet the condition are set to NaN, so first we multiply the series by 0.7 and leave only the rows where the condition is met, that is, the rows with the modern USD and use the other parameter to leave the rest of rows with initial value